# Python No module named 'requests_html' in Windows CMD

Tags: python, windows, cmd, python-requests-html

I am trying to create a script that Googles a string and then opens `X` first links in the browser, using **requests-HTML** module.
When I execute the code in my editor everything works fine, but when I execute the script from CMD I get an error indicating that there is no module called `requests_html`.

```
File "C:\Users\EM\PycharmProjects\Learn\Automate the Boring Stuff\lucky.py", line 6, in <module>
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution even though I do not fully understand why.
At first, I have installed the module from PyCharm, the script worked as intended when I ran it from there, but received the No Module error whenever I tried to run it from the command line cmd.exe.

**Solution:**
I tried installing the module from the command line, and it worked. Although I still do not comprehend why this happens. If anyone has an idea, please share it with me.

Comment: That is because PyCharm installs the module in the virutal environment within which the project is created. If you didn't initiate a virtual environment within CMD, it installed it globally. So when you installed with PyCharm, CMD has no knowledge of it as it is within a venv. When you install it in CMD, PyCharm has no idea of it, because PyCharm works within a venv

Comment: So a solution would be to always install the modules in both CMD and PyCharm?

Comment: The correct solution would be to always use the same virtual environment. If you're on Windows, then in order to activate the same venv, you have to type "workon NameOfYourVenv" inside of the CMD.